# Получение списка всех потоков (Thread) приложения

Tags: многопоточность, потоки-данных, visual-studio, .net, c#

Visual Studio при отладке .NET-программ показывает список существующих потоков с их статусом. Но никаких методов, позволяющих получить список управляемых потоков приложения, чтобы использовать его в коде, в самом .NET API нет. Насколько я смог найти, для того чтобы получить список потоков из того же места, откуда берёт их Студия, нужно через COM вызвать API отладчика. Не вариант. Список потоков ОС получается без проблем, но способа перейти от потока ОС к потоку .NET я тоже не нашёл.

Когда в одной программе мне потребовалось отслеживать состояние главного потока, я просто записал ссылку на него в глобальную переменную при старте. Но мне хотелось бы инкапсулировать библиотечный функционал таким образом, чтобы об этом не нужно было помнить. Библиотека сама должна найти поток, состояние которого ей нужно отслеживать.

Comment: Единственное, что приходит в голову, - это создать обертку над классом Thread (в которой и отслеживать создание и удаление потоков) и вынести ее во внешнюю библиотеку. А все потоки в приложении создавать с помощью этой обертки.

Comment: Угу. А если поток созаётся каким-нибудь BackgroundWorker или ThreadPool? Это не решение.<br>&nbsp;<br>

Я скорее думаю в сторону АОП. Создать аспект, который при вызове методов прописывает потоки, в которых вызваны эти методы, в глобальное хранилище потоков. И ещё периодически отслеживает состояние запомненных потоков, чтобы удалять из глобального хранилища завершившиеся потоки.<br>&nbsp;<br>

По-хорошему, нужно как-то залезть в потроха .NET и выцепить эту информацию оттуда. Рефлектор тут не поможет, т.к. у потоков существенная часть реализована через InternalCall.

Comment: >> А если поток созаётся каким-нибудь BackgroundWorker или ThreadPool? <br/>
А им нельзя подсунуть никакую фабрику потоков?

Comment: Нельзя :(

Answer (score 1):

> Но никаких методов, позволяющих получить список управляемых потоков приложения, чтобы использовать его в коде, в самом .NET API нет

Как же так? А как же [Process.Threads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.threads.aspx)?

Почему нельзя выполнить

```
Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads
```

?

**UPD**

В таком случае у вас мало возможностей. Основной способ: сделать базовый класс для всех своих потоков, и сделать некий менеджер потоков. И в базовом классе зашить намертво добавление/удаление себя в/из менеджера(а).

Comment: Я в курсе. Но этот вызов возвращает потоки операционной системы, которые не совпадают с потоками .NET. См. последнее предложение первого абзаца вопроса.

Comment: Только сейчас пришла в голову ещё одна мысль: а ведь для асинхронного логгера (где мне это, собственно, понадобилось), не так важно, это потоки .NET или операционной системы!